# What is the difference between "idiom and proverb"?

Tags: terminology, idiomaticity

For example 'Kick the bucket." Is it an idiom or proverb? How can I recognize them?

Comment: "kick the bucket" is an idiom because idioms are referential phraseological units, unlike proverbs. For example, "kick the bucket" is simply another way of saying "to die."

Comment: I don't know why this was closed, it seems valid to me.

Comment: I believe the key difference is that an idiom is a figurative referring expression, but a proverb is a proposition (which expresses a common truth). So idioms usually are not full sentences, but proverbs are.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I marked it as off-topic because it seems language-specific to me, a kind of question someone learning English would ask. To add to that, it has already been asked and answered here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43725/whats-the-difference-between-a-proverb-and-an-idiom. In general, if you feel that one of the moderators has wrongly put a question on hold, please flag it to be reopened. That way, mods get called for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "kick the bucket" is an idiom.

"Idiom"=It is a phrase that the meaning of separate words is different from whole phrase.

"Proverb"=It is a fix sentence.

So the differences between proverbs and idioms are:

1."Idioms" are phrases/part of a sentence but "proverbs" are full/fixed sentences.

2."Idioms"--> sometimes have variants      "Proverbs"-->have no variants

3."Idioms"--> are not intended to have moral lesson       "Proverbs"--> have a moral lesson( advice, warn,..)

4."Idioms"--> every type of text           "Proverbs"--> literally or sociocultural texts

5."Idioms"--> frequently used        "Proverbs"--> are less frequently used

6."Idioms"--> sometimes used literally        "Proverbs"-->rarely used literally

7."Idioms"--> figurative extension of the words meanings        "Proverbs"--> based on folklore, an event/a famous poet, a legends

Comment: I don't think your definition of proverb is accurate.